# how to check if due-date in rest api is greater than tomorrow

Tags: rest, go

I've written a todo handler API and want to add a condition to check if inputted DueDate by user is less than tomorrow date,how should I write it instead of ???? in following code?

```
type Todo struct {
    gorm.Model

    Title string `json:"title,omitempty"`
    Description string `json:"description,omitempty"`
    DueDate time.Time `json:"duedate,omitempty"`

    UserId uint   `json:"user_id"` //The user that this todo belongs to
}

func  ValidateTodo(todo *Todo) (map[string]interface{}, bool) {

    if todo.Title == "" {
        return u.Message(false, "Todo title should be on the payload"), false
    }

    if len(todo.Title)>30 {
        return u.Message(false, "Todo title should be less than 30 characters"), false
    }

    if todo.Description == "" {
        return u.Message(false, "Todo description should be on the payload"), false
    }

    if todo.DueDate<time.Now(){
       ?????
    }
    return u.Message(true, "success"), true

}
```

Comment: Take a look at time.Time.Add and time.Time.AddDate which lets you turn Now into "tomorrow". Compare Times with time.Time.{Before,After}.

Comment: operator < not defined on Time

Answer (score 2):

You an do this with a combination of [time.AddDate()](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.AddDate) and [time.Before()](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Before)

```
dueDate := time.Now()
tomorrow := time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, 1)

if tomorrow.Before(dueDate) {
    fmt.Println("Tomorrow is before your due date")
}
```

**Edit:** Volker's comment raises a good point actually. [time.After()](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.After) would probably make more logical sense to use for readability. So you could do the following;

```
dueDate := time.Now()
tomorrow := time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, 1)

if dueDate.After(tomorrow) {
    fmt.Println("Due date is after tomorrow")
}
```

**Edit2:** Update to zero out time based on the desire to have tomorrow's time at 00:00:00

```
tomorrow := time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, 1)
tomorrowZeroTime, err := time.Parse("Mon Jan 2 2006", tomorrow.Format("Mon Jan 2 2006"))
if err != nil {
    // Handle Error
}

dueDate := time.Now()
if dueDate.After(tomorrowZeroTime) {
    fmt.Println("Due date is after tomorrow")
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, its a good idea, but it will add 24hours to tomorrow according to current time, but I need to consider the date only not about the hour of the day.

Comment: `AddDate()` does *NOT* add 24 hours per day ([source](https://golang.org/src/time/time.go?s=29842:29901#L945)). It creates a brand new `time.Time` adding the specific number of year/month/days to the source time's date. Doing time.Duration calculations after a `AddDate(0,0,1)` will not always yield a 24 hour duration e.g. if the two dates span a DST shift.

Comment: Basically you want to zero out the time before you do your check from what I gather from that @Siasalar updated the answer with one way to do that. Essentially you format and re-parse. Unsure if there's a better way to do it personally.

Comment: thanks a lot guys, it helped me a lot and working properly.